# to_param is escaping / to '%2F'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the url to be `/s/:id/:name` by using:

```
def to_param
    "#{id}/#{name}".parameterize
end
```

however this will give the url `/s/:id%2F:name`

How can I stop rails from escaping the `/` ?

Comment: parameterize builds urls, so it'll escape the `/`. build in TWO pieces and parameterize each separately. `"#{id}".parameterize + "/" + "#{name}".parameterize`

Comment: @MarcB even if it's separated, or no `.parameterize` at all `/` is still escaped. `"#{id}" + "/" + "#{name}".parameterize`

Comment: does anything else "upstream" then do its own parameterizing?

Comment: @MarcB nothing.

Comment: If it's still escaped without the `parameterize` calls, then that's clearly not the problem. Post any other relevant code, too, or we have no hope of debugging it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode what relevant code do you mean? I can't think of any thing related. Also isn't escaping the `/` supposed to happen in rails?